# Debian bookworm won't print colors

Tags: debian, printer

With upgrade to Debian bookworm, color printer prints colors in gray.

Answer (score 0):

Fix system-wide:

```
System Settings | Printers | Unlock | right-click on your color printer | Properties | Printer Options | Print Color as Gray | Off
```

Or similarly fix each time you print like this:

[image]

Note, in LibreOffice 7 just setting it correctly when you print a document won't make it stick.  You need to specify this in

```
File | Printer settings... | Properties | Device | Print Color as Gray | Off
```